# cURL domain can access using browser but cant access using cURL

Tags: php, curl

i want to ask about cURL PHP.
i can access domain using browser , but when i access using cURL its return **Error: "Failed to connect to mydomain.com port 80: Timed out" - Code: 7**

this is my code :

```
$curlHandle = curl_init();
        $url="http://mydomain.go.net";
        curl_setopt($curlHandle,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
        curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
        curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,120);
        // $hasil = curl_exec($curlHandle);
        // curl_close($curlHandle); 

        // echo $hasil;

        if(!curl_exec($curlHandle)){
            die('Error: "' . curl_error($curlHandle) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curlHandle));
        }else{ //do something else
            echo "berhasil";
            // curl_exec($curlHandle);
        }
```

please help me, thanks!

Comment: `Failed to connect ... port 80` means that either there's no server listening to that port or your network prevented the TCP connection attempt to reach that server from wherever your PHP program runs.

Comment: enable CURLOPT_VERBOSE and post the verbose log